# React Docs - origin of "serverRequest"

Tags: reactjs

On React doc here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
      var lastGist = result[0];
      this.setState({
        username: lastGist.owner.login,
        lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

Where `serverRequest` come from? Is it an attribute of a React Component?

Comment: It's just an declaration of an instance variable, just like `componentDidMount` is a declaration of an instance method

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation page that you reference has been removed, but a very similar example is shown in a [Lynda video](https://www.lynda.com/React-js-tutorials/Adding-lifecycle-methods-setting-state/495271/511724-4.html) that I'm watching.  Some additional context from this particular video is the following code ([see full](https://github.com/planetoftheweb/reactinterface/blob/02_04e/process/js/app.js)):

```
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  this.serverRequest.abort();
},
```

While the video did not go into detail about the inclusion, I've deduced that the `abort` method is actually part of [jQuery's AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  The `serverRequest` property is simply being attached to the component so that the AJAX request can be accessed elsewhere in the component's life-cycle.

Unless I'm mistaken, the property name is arbitrary and could have just as easily been called `ajaxRequest`.